# Arabic text go under baseline when vocalisation diacritics (tashkil) is used

Tags: polyglossia, arabic, paracol, baseline, diacritical-mark

When an Arabic text is vocalized (using the diacritics called *tashkil*), the whole line sometimes goes below the expected baseline.

Here is an example with the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,french]{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{polyglossia}




\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Ligatures=TeX,Script=Arabic]{Amiri}

\setotherlanguages{arabic}


\begin{document}



\begin{paracol}{2}
  \switchcolumn[0]
  Correct baseline

  \switchcolumn[1]
  Incorrect baseline

  \switchcolumn[0]
  \textarabic{لوغيم إپسوم دولور}\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\paperwidth}{0.4pt}} 

  \switchcolumn[1]
  \vbox{\textarabic{لُوغِيمْ إپْسُومْ دُلُورْ}}

  \switchcolumn[0]
  \textarabic{لوغيم إپسوم دولور}\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\paperwidth}{0.4pt}} 

  \switchcolumn[1]
  \vbox{\textarabic{لُوغِيمْ إپْسُومْ دُلُورْ}}
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

Witch give the following rendering:

[image: Rendering]

I used `paracol` here to put the expected behavior and the bad one in parallel. So, as you see, if the `paracol` line is preceded by a full Latin-written line, then the vocalization does not undergo any shift.

But — and this is the main problem — when the `paracol` line is preceded by a full Arabic line, then the shift occurs.

#### The question

So, how can I force a vocalized Arabic text to always respect the assigned baseline in any situation?

Comment: you could either increase the baseline spacing so it fits, or tell tex to always observe the spacing even if the diacritics over-print the line above, which do you want?

Comment: the latin text in your example has no descenders, add Qgggppp

Comment: @MaxChernoff: Not sure why you've reverted my change to the title - "[tashkil](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tashkil)" is the word that is used when writing in English to refer to Arabic vocalisation; "chakl" is a French transliteration, and searching for it produces results that are not nearly as useful...

Comment: @psmears I'm completely unfamiliar with Arabic, but it showed up in the review queues so I made a snap judgment. Following your explanation, I've unreverted your edit, so it should be correct now. Sorry!

Comment: @MaxChernoff: Fair enough, thanks :)

Comment: @psmears I approve your change. BTW, tashkil is the most common transliteration in English because most english speakers how speak Arabic too com from mashrek where we name vocalization (in Arabic) _tashkil_. Whereas people from maghreb use (in arabic too) the word _chakl_. So, it’s just Arabic how bring two ways to name the same think depending on regional variants. So, I suggest to put in the title “tashkil—chakl” to match both regional variants.

Comment: @fauve: Thanks :). It's also the difference between English and French - people who are familiar with French are more likely to transliterate شكل as "chakl", because "ch" in French accurately represents the sound of ش - but because in English "ch" makes a different sound it's standard to transliterate as (for example) "shakl".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

The text is taller than the specified baseline spacing

so you can increase the space (bbb)  or allow the diacritics to over-print descenders on the line above (ccc) or compromise and increase the space enough to avoid most overlap but still allow it if a diacritic happens under a long descender (ddd)

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,french]{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{polyglossia}




\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Ligatures=TeX,Script=Arabic]{Amiri}

\setotherlanguages{arabic}

\def\test{%
\begin{paracol}{2}
  \switchcolumn[0]
  Correct baseline

  \switchcolumn[1]
  Incorrect baseline

  \switchcolumn[0]
  \textarabic{لوغيم إپسوم دولور}\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\paperwidth}{0.4pt}} 

  \switchcolumn[1]
  \vbox{\textarabic{لُوغِيمْ إپْسُومْ دُلُورْ}}

  \switchcolumn[0]
  \textarabic{لوغيم إپسوم دولور}\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\paperwidth}{0.4pt}} 

  \switchcolumn[1]
  \vbox{\textarabic{لُوغِيمْ إپْسُومْ دُلُورْ}}
\end{paracol}%
}
\begin{document}

aaa

\test

\bigskip
bbb

{\def\baselinestretch{1.5}\normalsize
\test

}


\bigskip
ccc

{\lineskiplimit=-20pt
\test

}


\bigskip
ddd

{\lineskiplimit=-10pt
\def\baselinestretch{1.2}\normalsize
\test

}
\end{document}
```